# iOS CAAnimation along with keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, uiview

I want to animate a layer at the same pace as the keyboard using CAAnimation.

I know that I can extract the keyboard's animation duration and curve number and create a UIView animation that fits the problem but I would like to do that same animation using CAAnimations.

Is there a way to get the keyboard's animation UIBezierPath for the curve or to get that same curve from the UIView animation?